# Запись регулярно выражения Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Вот пример регулярного выражения

```
select NAME from table where NAME RLIKE '^тест$'
```

Но как быть, если этот самый 'тест' заранее неизвестен и поступает из php формы по AJAX? При обычном запросе с использованием LIKE все также предельно просто и понятно, а как быть в такой ситуации?
Была идея предварительно преобразовывать получаемую строку в массив и работать с каждым элементом, но дальше идеи никак не продвинулся.

Comment: А какая разница между LIKE и RLIKE? и там, и там шаблон - тупо строковый литерал.

Comment: @Akina есть необходимость учесть введение при поиске знаков препинания, ошибки

Comment: Почему бы просто не подставить вместо тест `$_POST['field']`? Где `field` ключ в который запихиваются данные перед отправкой.

Comment: Сейчас я просто сравниваю содержимое полей с получаемым $text.

Comment: @wcobalt сейчас так и реализовано. Однако хотелось бы реализовать возможность поиска, допустим, при условии что пользователь ввел не "клей" и "клеи".